# About Atomic Armors in Fallout 3

Tags: fallout-3

How can I equip the various atomic armor in Fallout 3?
I am already at level 22 but I still can't find anyone who can train me for equipping them.
They are really good armors...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean the Power armors? (Maybe this is a regional version difference in nomenclature)

You can get power armor training by asking the brotherhood of steel about it after rescuing the scientists from project purity.

Alternatively, if Operation: Anchorage is installed, completing the sim will allow you to wear power armor.

Comment: Yes it was the Power Armor. Thank you very much. I'm playing the Italian version and it really sucks with the translation! I wish to play it in english but it's impossible. Thanks again :)